# Как менять изображение в Activity, когда меняется Fragment во ViewPager

Tags: java, android

Есть `ViewPager` с тремя фрагментами, при изменение фрагментов, нужно изменять `ImageView` в `Activity`. Как это сделать? Как сообщить `Activity`, какой сейчас фрагмент на экране.

Код `ViewPagerAdapter`:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Добавление фрагментов в Адаптер:

```
   private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new CallFragment(), String.valueOf(getText(R.string.main_activity_tab_call)));
        adapter.addFragment(new ChatFragment(), String.valueOf(getText(R.string.main_activity_tab_chat)));
        adapter.addFragment(new ContactFragment(), String.valueOf(getText(R.string.main_activity_tab_contact)));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Привет ты таб используешь ?я прально понел при прокрутке должен быть переход с  одного фрагмента на другой в зоне видимости?

Comment: @elik Использую TabLayout, при скролле идет переход с одного фрагмента на другой

Comment: Все понел  бери пример снизу он рабочий я с проекта своего взял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
//тут вставляете картинку в imageView
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

**Дополнение**:

Для TabLayout можно использовать это

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                 //тут вставляете картинку в imageView

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот адаптер

```
   private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ƏSAS");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "VIRTUAL TUR");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "ÜNVANIMIZ");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);



Вот класик
```

```html
 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Не забудь обьявить

```
   CustomViewPager viewPager = (CustomViewPager ) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
```